# Simulating a hotplug event with libusb (test, debugging)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, libusb, libusb-1.0

How can I simulate a *fake* hotplug removal event with [libusb](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/)?

I'm writing an application that uses `libusb-1.0` on Linux and MacOS to detect and respond to [USB Hotplug Events](https://libusb.sourceforge.io/api-1.0/libusb_hotplug.html) (eg the user ejects a USB drive and then I run some code).

I'm trying to do some manual testing (and eventually some automated unit tests) for making sure my application functions as desired when a USB drive is removed. For example, I'd like to be able to do this on a GitHub shared runner running on MacStadium's fleet of MacMinis in the cloud. Obviously, I can't physically stick a USB drive into the cloud machine and remove the USB drive during the CI pipeline.

How can I simulate a USB hotplug removal event in `libusb` for testing my application?

Comment: Hey, did you have any luck in finding a solution for your request? Having the same need in order to unit test my application for working properly on USB hotplug connect/disconnect events. Any feedbay would be appreciated. Regards.